# try catch block indentation in Emacs

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I'm using the bsd style of indentation in emacs & I'd like to modify it a bit.  The related portion of my .emacs file is below.  When I write a function with try catch blocks the braces are indented.  I'd like them to not indent similar to a function.

What's it's doing now.

```
try 
    {
    }
catch 
    {
    }
```

What I'd like it to do.

```
try 
{
}
catch 
{
}
```

.emacs file

```
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  ;; my customizations for all of c-mode and related modes
  ;; other customizations can go here
  (setq c-default-style "bsd")
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)
  (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
  )

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language? Different languages use different modes, and different indenting logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the line with the indent you'd like to change and press C-c C-o.  This runs c-set-offset and defaults to the current line's syntax (in this case substatement-open).  '+' means one level of indent, '-' means one level unindent, and '0' means no additional indent.  You want 0.  To make it permanent, add (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0) to your hook.